# Align axis ticks with bins in a lattice histogram

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I plotted a histogram using Lattice

```
histogram(~Time |factor(Bila), data=flexi2, xlim= c(5, 15), ylim=c(0, 57),
      scales=list(x=list(at=seq(5,15,1))), xlab="Time", 
      subset=(Bila%in% c("")))`
```

The bins I get do not match the exact hours, whereas I would like the bin to start at the exact hour, for example, 6,7 etc. I use lattice since I want conditional histograms. I have extracted here just one histogram to illustrate.
[image]

UPDATE:
Here is a reproducible example (I hope) as was requested. As can be seen 0 for example is not at the limit of bins.

```
x<-rnorm(1000)
histogram(~x)
```

[image]

Comment: Is `Time` numeric or a factor/character vector? It will help if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2954547).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you specified the x axis scale with `scales = list(x = list(at = 5:15))`, but you didn't actually change the breakpoints. It happens in the default case as well: the default axis labels are integers, but the default breakpoints are determined programmatically and are not necessarily integers unless you have integer-valued data.

An easy fix would be to specify your own breaks in the `breaks` argument:

```
histogram(~Time |factor(Bila), data=flexi2, subset=(Bila %in% c("")),
  xlim= c(5, 15), ylim=c(0, 57),
  breaks = 5:15,
  scales = list(x = list(at = 5:15)),
  xlab="Time")
```

And an example:

```
library(lattice)
x <- rnorm(1000)
x[abs(x) > 3] <- 3
x_breaks <- c(-3, -1.5, 0, 1.5, 3)
histogram(~ x,
          title = "Defaults")
histogram(~ x, breaks = x_breaks,
          title = "Custom bins, default tickmarks")
histogram(~ x, scales = list(x = list(at = x_breaks)),
          title = "Custom tickmarks, default bins")
histogram(~ x, breaks = x_breaks, scales = list(x = list(at = x_breaks)),
          title = "Custom tickmarks, custom bins")
```